# One plot for each period from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

From [this](https://anonymousfiles.io/4RIEdyJO/) .csv I create a dataframe,

```
dfi = pd.read_csv('dfi.csv')
dfi['date'] = pd.to_datetime(dfi['date'])
dfi = dfi.set_index('date')

dfi
Out[181]: 
           value
date            
2019-09-19     a
2019-09-19     a
2019-09-25     b
2019-09-11     a
2019-09-19     a
         ...
2019-09-19     a
2019-09-11     a
2019-09-19     a
2019-09-16     a
2019-09-11     a

[100 rows x 1 columns]
```

I can plot the occurrences of each value doing,

```
dfi['value'].value_counts().plot.bar()
```

[image: Histogram for the whole dataset]

I can also get the counts per period by doing,

```
dfi.to_period(myPeriod).groupby('date')['value'].value_counts()
Out[183]: 
date                   value
2019-09-09/2019-09-15  a        32
2019-09-16/2019-09-22  a        49
                       b         1
                       d         1
2019-09-23/2019-09-29  a        11
                       b         3
                       d         2
                       c         1
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

But I cannot manage to get a plot for each period. My natural guess was,

```
dfi.to_period(myPeriod).groupby('date')['value'].value_counts().plot.bar()
```

[image: split histogram]

slipts the categories in (period,value) instead,

How can I get one histogram for each period?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) the values into a cross table and use the `subplots` parameter in the plot function as shown in the third example for [`plot.bar()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html):

```
dfi.to_period("W").groupby('date')['value'].value_counts().unstack(0).plot.bar(subplots=True, legend=None, rot=0)
```

[image]